# Unable to set "max" without setting tickInterval in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, max, yaxis

We have been working on an application where we are migrating from one type of charts to highcharts. I have a situation where the `max` value is available but I do not have any `min` value. Without setting any `tickInterval` I am not able to get the desired max value on my chart. I have tried `alignTicks: false` and `endOnTick: false` also. I can set tickInterval but the problem is I am not sure what would be the max value since it is very dynamic in nature. Is there any way I can fix this issue? Is there any attribute that I can set?
I have a fiddle attached: [Unable to set max without tick interval](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ShashiNandivada/0ktzunwm/11/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ewolden My problem is, I want to be able to set the exact max that I set in my JSON without having to calculate the tickInterval. Adding softMax also did not help.

Comment: But that would not give the max value as mentioned in the JSON.

Comment: Have you tried using `setExtremes` function with the first argument set to `null`?: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/6fbsupaL/